# Python_textinput issue while using two instances of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm working on a choice based adventure game with python, and I'm using pygame to create some graphics for the game.

As I was trying to create a screen so the player can input his real name and the main character name I faced an issue: as I try to create both text inputs (using [pygame_textinput module](https://github.com/Nearoo/pygame-text-input/blob/master/pygame_textinput.py)) on the same screen, it just clones what I write in one of them.

I thought I could solve this by putting the other input on a new screen but when I hit enter on the first screen it just passes through the rest of the code and the second input stays empty.

How could I solve this issue?

```
#Imports
import contextlib
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    import pygame
import pickle
import time
import random
import pygame_textinput.pygame_textinput as textinput

#Really messy, I know#

#Save Stuff
Choices = {}

def save(to_save, save_filepath):
    pickle.dump(to_save, open(save_filepath, "wb"))

def load(save_filepath):
    return pickle.load(open(save_filepath, "rb"))

#Initializations
pygame.init()

#Screen
scrWidth = 640
scrHeight = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((scrWidth, scrHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Something')

#Images
startscreenbg = pygame.image.load('assets/Images/startscreen.jpg').convert()

#Text Input
real_nametxtinput = textinput.TextInput(text_color=(255,255,255))
char_nametxtinput = textinput.TextInput(text_color=(255,255,255))

#Clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Game Constants
next = False
real_name = ''
char_name = ''
real_name_done = False
char_name_done = False

##### Global Functions #####

#Buttons stuff
buttonTextFont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 20)
def createButton(msg, msgcolor,x,y,width,height,color1,color2,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+width > mouse[0] > x and y+height > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color2,(x,y,width,height))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color1,(x,y,width,height))

    buttontext = buttonTextFont.render(msg, 1, msgcolor)
    screen.blit(buttontext, (x + (width//2) - (buttontext.get_width()//2), (y + (height//2) - (buttontext.get_height()//2))))



##### Screens/Chapters #####
def update_next1():
    global next
    next = True

def start_screen():
    screen.blit(startscreenbg, (0, 0))
    new_game = createButton('New Game',(255,255,255), 80, 100, 200, 50, (0,180,0), (0,255,0), update_next1)
    load_game = createButton('Load Game', (255,255,255), 360, 100, 200, 50, (0,0,180), (0,0,255))

#Names
def real_name_screen():
    global real_name, real_name_done
    screen.blit(startscreenbg, (0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (102, 255, 102), (150, 90, 200, 50))
    screen.blit(real_nametxtinput.get_surface(), (150,100))
    if real_nametxtinput.update(events):
        real_name = real_nametxtinput.get_text()
        real_name_done = True


def char_name_screen():
    global char_name, char_name_done
    screen.blit(startscreenbg, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 102, 255), (150, 90, 200, 50))
    screen.blit(char_nametxtinput.get_surface(), (150, 100))
    if char_nametxtinput.update(events):
        char_name = char_nametxtinput.get_text()
        if char_name != '':
            char_name_done = True



run = True
while run:

    clock.tick(27)

    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if not next:
        start_screen()
    if next:
        real_name_screen()
        if real_name_done:
            char_name_screen()
            if char_name_done:
                #This is just so I could test it
                print(real_name, char_name)
                run = False



    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to keep track if one of the text input widgets is active, and a way to switch between all widgets.

I hacked together this example, adjust as needed (there's a lot that could be improved):

```
import os.path

import pygame
import pygame.locals as pl

pygame.font.init()

class WidgetManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.widgets = []

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for w in self.widgets:
                    w.active = False
                    if w.rect.collidepoint(e.pos):
                        w.active = True

        for w in self.widgets:
            w.update(events, dt)

    def draw(self, surface):
        for w in self.widgets:
            surface.blit(w.surface, w.rect)

class TextInput:
    """
    This class lets the user input a piece of text, e.g. a name or a message.
    This class let's the user input a short, one-lines piece of text at a blinking cursor
    that can be moved using the arrow-keys. Delete, home and end work as well.
    """
    def __init__(
            self,
            initial_string="",
            font_family="",
            font_size=35,
            antialias=True,
            active=False,
            text_color=(0, 0, 0),
            rect=pygame.Rect(0, 0, 10, 10),
            cursor_color=(0, 0, 1),
            repeat_keys_initial_ms=400,
            repeat_keys_interval_ms=35):
        """
        :param initial_string: Initial text to be displayed
        :param font_family: name or list of names for font (see pygame.font.match_font for precise format)
        :param font_size:  Size of font in pixels
        :param antialias: Determines if antialias is applied to font (uses more processing power)
        :param text_color: Color of text (duh)
        :param cursor_color: Color of cursor
        :param repeat_keys_initial_ms: Time in ms before keys are repeated when held
        :param repeat_keys_interval_ms: Interval between key press repetition when helpd
        """

        # Text related vars:
        self.antialias = antialias
        self.text_color = text_color
        self.font_size = font_size
        self.input_string = initial_string  # Inputted text
        self.active = active
        self.rect = rect

        if not os.path.isfile(font_family):
            font_family = pygame.font.match_font(font_family)

        self.font_object = pygame.font.Font(font_family, font_size)

        # Text-surface will be created during the first update call:
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((1, 1))
        self.surface.set_alpha(0)

        # Vars to make keydowns repeat after user pressed a key for some time:
        self.keyrepeat_counters = {}  # {event.key: (counter_int, event.unicode)} (look for "***")
        self.keyrepeat_intial_interval_ms = repeat_keys_initial_ms
        self.keyrepeat_interval_ms = repeat_keys_interval_ms

        # Things cursor:
        self.cursor_surface = pygame.Surface((int(self.font_size/20+1), self.font_size))
        self.cursor_surface.fill(cursor_color)
        self.cursor_position = len(initial_string)  # Inside text
        self.cursor_visible = True  # Switches every self.cursor_switch_ms ms
        self.cursor_switch_ms = 500  # /|\
        self.cursor_ms_counter = 0

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and self.active:
                self.cursor_visible = True  # So the user sees where he writes

                # If none exist, create counter for that key:
                if event.key not in self.keyrepeat_counters:
                    self.keyrepeat_counters[event.key] = [0, event.unicode]

                if event.key == pl.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.input_string = (
                        self.input_string[:max(self.cursor_position - 1, 0)]
                        + self.input_string[self.cursor_position:]
                    )

                    # Subtract one from cursor_pos, but do not go below zero:
                    self.cursor_position = max(self.cursor_position - 1, 0)
                elif event.key == pl.K_DELETE:
                    self.input_string = (
                        self.input_string[:self.cursor_position]
                        + self.input_string[self.cursor_position + 1:]
                    )

                elif event.key == pl.K_RETURN:
                    return True

                elif event.key == pl.K_RIGHT:
                    # Add one to cursor_pos, but do not exceed len(input_string)
                    self.cursor_position = min(self.cursor_position + 1, len(self.input_string))

                elif event.key == pl.K_LEFT:
                    # Subtract one from cursor_pos, but do not go below zero:
                    self.cursor_position = max(self.cursor_position - 1, 0)

                elif event.key == pl.K_END:
                    self.cursor_position = len(self.input_string)

                elif event.key == pl.K_HOME:
                    self.cursor_position = 0

                else:
                    # If no special key is pressed, add unicode of key to input_string
                    self.input_string = (
                        self.input_string[:self.cursor_position]
                        + event.unicode
                        + self.input_string[self.cursor_position:]
                    )
                    self.cursor_position += len(event.unicode)  # Some are empty, e.g. K_UP

            elif event.type == pl.KEYUP:
                # *** Because KEYUP doesn't include event.unicode, this dict is stored in such a weird way
                if event.key in self.keyrepeat_counters:
                    del self.keyrepeat_counters[event.key]

        # Update key counters:
        for key in self.keyrepeat_counters:
            self.keyrepeat_counters[key][0] += dt  # Update clock

            # Generate new key events if enough time has passed:
            if self.keyrepeat_counters[key][0] >= self.keyrepeat_intial_interval_ms:
                self.keyrepeat_counters[key][0] = (
                    self.keyrepeat_intial_interval_ms
                    - self.keyrepeat_interval_ms
                )

                event_key, event_unicode = key, self.keyrepeat_counters[key][1]
                pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(pl.KEYDOWN, key=event_key, unicode=event_unicode))

        # Re-render text surface:
        self.surface = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size)
        self.surface.blit(self.font_object.render(self.input_string, self.antialias, self.text_color), (0, 0))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.text_color, (0, 0, *self.rect.size), 1)

        # Update self.cursor_visible
        self.cursor_ms_counter += dt
        if self.cursor_ms_counter >= self.cursor_switch_ms:
            self.cursor_ms_counter %= self.cursor_switch_ms
            self.cursor_visible = not self.cursor_visible

        if self.cursor_visible and self.active:
            cursor_y_pos = self.font_object.size(self.input_string[:self.cursor_position])[0]
            # Without this, the cursor is invisible when self.cursor_position > 0:
            if self.cursor_position > 0:
                cursor_y_pos -= self.cursor_surface.get_width()
            self.surface.blit(self.cursor_surface, (cursor_y_pos, 0))

        return False

    def get_surface(self):
        return self.surface

    def get_text(self):
        return self.input_string

    def get_cursor_position(self):
        return self.cursor_position

    def set_text_color(self, color):
        self.text_color = color

    def set_cursor_color(self, color):
        self.cursor_surface.fill(color)

    def clear_text(self):
        self.input_string = ""
        self.cursor_position = 0

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    manager = WidgetManager()
    manager.widgets.append(TextInput(text_color=pygame.Color('grey'), cursor_color=pygame.Color('grey'), rect=pygame.Rect(5, 5, 790, 35)))
    manager.widgets.append(TextInput(text_color=pygame.Color('orange'), cursor_color=pygame.Color('orange'), rect=pygame.Rect(5, 55, 790, 35), active=True))
    dt = 0
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        manager.draw(screen)
        manager.update(events, dt)
        dt = clock.tick()
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You see `TextInput` now has an `active` flag. If it's not set, the key input is ignored. Also, we store the position and size of `TextInput` in the new attribute `rect`, so the new class `WidgetManager` can switch between the widgets by clicking one with the mouse.

I also removed the `Clock` from the `TextInput` class, since calling `self.clock.tick()` is something the main loop should do.

[image]

Comment: It seems to work really well but I have 2 questions: how can I implement it on my previous code and set the place that I want the textinput box to appear? And how do I set the value that the player inputs to a var? (Sorry if it is an obvious answer, but I'm not a really advanced python user)